# Параметризация метода

Tags: java

1. Как параметризуется метод при использовании Generic и в какой момент при параметризации методов в коде известны типы параметров
2. зачем отдельно параметризовать статические методы

Если можно, то с примерами.

Answer (score 1):

1) примерно так (из The Java™ Tutorials:)

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o); // Correct
    }
}
```

В том же туториале утверждается, что компилятор распознаёт тип и т.д. Значит на этапе компиляции уже кое-что известно.

2) Вопрос не понятен. Что значит "отдельно параметризовать"? Вроде в том же файле с исходным кодом класса все делается? Т.е. ничего особливого для статических методов нет.

Вверху был статический, тут напишем не статический. Всё одинаково:

```
public <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o); // Correct
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: `Значит на этапе компиляции уже кое-что известно.` Если я не ошибаюсь, то в java обобщения только на этапе компиляции и существуют.

Comment: А что  будет ели в праметризоанном методе
не будет аргументов, как в этом случае компилятор определяет тип подставляемых данных.

Comment: @LittleBudda Значит параметр задает возвращаемое значение? Так сразу е не сообразишь. Обычно тип так или иначе передаётся через аргумент, не припомню чтобы без аргумента. Но можно предположить, что тип выводится из левой части выражения или явно указывается при вызове метода Object o = a.<MyClass>method(). Надо проверить, мануалы покурить.

Comment: @LittleBudda  метод принимает и отдаёт. Если не указывать параметры , значит останется указать только , то что нужно отдать   Если это ваш дженерик , то его и указываете